# Why doesn't opentok subscriber video show up in my cordova/phonegap app?

Tags: ios, cordova, opentok, tokbox

The following code works fine on a desktop browser exactly how it is, but isn't working in my phone gap/cordova app.  My output says connect and iOS received stream, but nothing is showing up in the body of my app.  This is in my index.js file:

```
var app = {
initialize: function() {
    this.bindEvents();
},

bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

////////////////////////////////
//////Start of my opentok code////////////

    var apiKey = '21692492';

    var sessionId = '2_MX4yMTY5MTQ5Mn5-RnJpIEZlYiAwNyAwODozMjozOSBQU1QgMjAxNH4wLjIwMzc2MDV-';

    var token = 'T1==cGFydG5lcl9pZD0yMTY5MTQ5MiZzaWc9ZWUxMTNjNjZiYjlkNWI4NTkwZTE2MDZiMjM0MzFkOWYyMzhiYzgxNjpzZXNzaW9uX2lkPTJfTVg0eU1UWTVNVFE1TW41LVJuSnBJRVpsWWlBd055QXdPRG96TWpvek9TQlFVMVFnTWpBeE5INHdMakl3TXpjMk1EVi0mY3JlYXRlX3RpbWU9MTM5MTc5MDgwNSZyb2xlPXB1Ymxpc2hlciZub25jZT0xMzkxNzkwODA1LjIzMzk0MTE4MzcyJmV4cGlyZV90aW1lPTEzOTQzODI4MDU=';


    function connectedHandler(event) {
        for (var i = 0; i < event.streams.length; i++) {
            var newDiv = $('<div />', {id:event.streams[i].streamId});
            $('body').append(newDiv);
            session.subscribe(event.streams[i], event.streams[i].streamId,{});
        }
    }


    var session = TB.initSession(sessionId);

    session.addEventListener('sessionConnected', connectedHandler);

    session.connect(apiKey, token);

//////End of my opentok code////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////
},

receivedEvent: function(id) {
    var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
    var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
    var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

    listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
}
};
```

This is the output I get:

```
2014-02-07 11:44:19.407 HelloCordova[2377:60b] iOS Connected to Session
2014-02-07 11:44:19.408 HelloCordova[2377:60b] object for session is {
connection =     {
    connectionId = "4B191468-46D5-4414-A46A-5C97376D6F2E";
    creationTime = 1391791459;
};
connectionCount = 0;
environment = production;
sessionConnectionStatus = OTSessionConnectionStatusConnected;
sessionId = "2_MX4yMTY5MTQ5Mn5-RnJpIEZlYiAwNyAwODozMjozOSBQU1QgMjAxNH4wLjIwMzc2MDV-";
streams =     (
);
}
2014-02-07 11:44:19.456 HelloCordova[2377:60b] iOS Received Stream
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working and what I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova plugin is modeled after OpenTok JS 2.2. In this new version, there are several changes. First of all, 'addEventListener' has been renamed to 'on'. To add events, you can do this:

```
session.on({
  'sessionConnected': function(event){
    session.publish( publisher );
  },
  'streamCreated': function(event){
    var newDiv = $('<div />', {id:event.stream.streamId});
    $('body').append(newDiv);
    session.subscribe(event.stream, event.stream.streamId, {});
  }
})
```

Note the following changes:
* addEventListener no longer exists
* on sessionConnected events, you no longer get an array of existing streams in the session. Every stream in the session will trigger a streamCreated event.
* streamCreated event callback parameter only has 1 stream element. This event will be triggered once for every stream

Here's a list of coming v2.2 changes: http://labs.tokbox.com/javascript-2.2

I have added some working sample code for you to reference: https://github.com/songz/cordova-plugin-opentok/blob/master/README.md#sample-code